# Threadpool object created using CreateThreadpoolWait() with multiple EVENT objects

Tags: multithreading, winapi, threadpool

I am doing this exercise to understand Threadpool created by CreateThreadpoolWait(). I create just ONE threadpool object using CreateThreadpoolWait(). I create 5 EVENT objects and submit to threadPool using SetThreadpoolWait(). Then I call setEvent() on 5 EVENT objects. My call back function gets called ONLY once. I was expecting the callback function to get called 5 times, because I had inserted 5 event objects. Is this the way thread pool created by CreateThreadpoolWait() behaves?

I could not find any sample that uses multiple EVENTS with single Threadpool object  created by CreateThreadpoolWait(). Going by the result of my experiments, thread pool object created by CreateThreadpoolWait() is bound to one EVENT object. Is my understanding correct?

```
//Callback function
const int g_cEvents = 5;
const int g_ThreadPoolCount = 1;
HANDLE g_hEvents[g_cEvents];
void CALLBACK WaitCallBack( PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE inst, PVOID context,
                        PTP_WAIT wait, TP_WAIT_RESULT WairR)
{
    UINT_PTR i = reinterpret_cast<UINT_PTR>(context);
    printf("Wait: result = %u, event#%p (tid = %u)\n",WairR, i,GetCurrentThreadId());
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILETIME TimerStartTime;
    char str[] = "Ok";
    PTP_WAIT Waitpool[g_ThreadPoolCount];


    for(int i = 0; i < g_cEvents; i++)
            g_hEvents[i] = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    const _int64 dwSEC   = ((_int64) 10000000);

    //Set the timer to fire in 20 second.
    ULARGE_INTEGER ulDueTime;
    ulDueTime.QuadPart = (ULONGLONG) - (20 * dwSEC);
    TimerStartTime.dwHighDateTime = ulDueTime.HighPart;
    TimerStartTime.dwLowDateTime  = ulDueTime.LowPart;

    for(int i = 0; i < g_ThreadPoolCount; i++)
        Waitpool[i] = CreateThreadpoolWait(WaitCallBack, str, 0);


    for(int i = 0; i < g_cEvents; i++)
        SetThreadpoolWait( Waitpool[0], g_hEvents[i] , &TimerStartTime);

    for(int i = 0; i < g_cEvents; i++)
        SetEvent(g_hEvents[i]);

    Sleep(1*60*1000); //1min sleep

    for(int i = 0; i < g_ThreadPoolCount; i++)
        WaitForThreadpoolWaitCallbacks(Waitpool[i] ,true);

    for(int i = 0; i < g_ThreadPoolCount; i++)
        CloseThreadpoolWait(Waitpool[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each wait object waits for one event. When you call `SetThreadpoolWait` with a new handle, it replaces the previous one. This makes sense when you realize that `SetThreadpoolWait` cannot fail (it returns void) so it cannot allocate memory. Therefore, it cannot maintain a list of all handles.

Comment: Raymond, Thanks for response. Following from Richter's book confused me. "Internally, the thread pool calls WaitForMultipleObjects(), passing in to it the set of handles that have been registered via the SetThreadpoolWait()....so that the thread pool thread wakes up whenever any of the handles becomes signaled. Because WaitForMultipleObjects has a limit of 64 (MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS) handles.., the thread pool really uses one thread per 64 objects"

Comment: Raymond, Thanks for response. Richter's book made me think that multiple k-objects can be put in to queue by calling SetThreadPoolWait(). Richter say: "....Internally, the thread pool calls WaitForMultipleObjects(), passing in to it the set of handles that have been registered via the SetThreadpoolWait()....so that the thread pool thread wakes up whenever any of the handles becomes signaled. Because WaitForMultipleObjects has a limit of 64 (MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS) handles.., the thread pool really uses one thread per 64 objects..."

Comment: Each wait object waits for only one event, but you can have more than one wait object.

Comment: Thanks Harry. I think this thread pool is good for holding one event object of one count.